# Before update trigger fails in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've created a trigger which should fire everey time I update the firstName of a worker in my table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON t_workers 
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     insert into t_logtable 
     values (pk_workerid , sysdate, :old.firstName)
  END;
```

But every time I try to update a row, this is the error I got:

> ora-04098 trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

What is wrong with the trigger?

And as you can see, the point would be to insert old values before update, isn't there any oracle solution, for an universial variable/column name? I mean not :`old.firstName`, but something, that would check any column, and gets any old value, that has been updated. It could be `firstName`, `lastName`, `salary` anything.

Comment: you forget add ; after insert code

Comment: You should have received a "Trigger created with compilation warnings" when you created it. Once you get that do a `show errors` to see the actual error - that would have told you that you forgot the `;` to end the `insert` statement

Comment: `show errors` doesn't always work, IME; however, you can always do `select * from user_errors` to find out more information.

Comment: thank you, everything works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON t_workers 
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     insert into t_logtable 
     values (pk_workerid , sysdate, :old.firstName);
  END;
```

**add ; after insert code**